# flask manage.py runserver can't pass parameter

Tags: python, flask, flask-script

user manager.py runserver my flask webframework can start on http://127.0.0.1:5000 but it can not access on other computer in network.
so i need use an open IP in network.
although i use bellow command:

```
manage.py runserver 192.168.49.25:8000
```

it can not run and give a error info:

```
manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 192.168.49.25:8000
```

I don't known what's wrong with it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/):

> Externally Visible Server If you run the server you will notice that
>   the server is only accessible from your own computer, not from any
>   other in the network. This is the default because in debugging mode a
>   user of the application can execute arbitrary Python code on your
>   computer.
>
> If you have debug disabled or trust the users on your network, you can
>   make the server publicly available simply by changing the call of the
>   run() method to look like this:
>
> `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` This tells your operating system to listen on
>   all public IPs.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use Flask-Script (python manage.py runserver) to run your Flask Application you can use the parameter --host to run it on a public IP.

```
python manage.py runserver --host 0.0.0.0
```

see also: https://flask-runner.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: This is almost the right answer. It should be `python manage.py runserver --host 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Use --port to run it on specific port.
`python manage.py runserver --host 0.0.0.0  --port 5001`

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Flask-Script then you have a way to get your host defined in your code.

```
from yourapp import create_app
from flask_script import Manager, Server
from yourapp import config

app = create_app(config.DevelopmentConfig)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command("runserver", Server(host=app.config['HOST'], port=app.config['PORT']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

now the server host and port will come from config

Comment: Hi @Yash Pokar, feel free to check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191126/unable-to-make-my-script-process-locally-created-server-response) just in case there is any solution to offer. Thanks.