# Unable to make my script process locally created server response in the right way

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-scraping, scrapy

I've used a script to run selenium locally so that I can make use of the response (derived from selenium) within my spider.

This is the web service where selenium runs locally:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Selenium(Resource):
    _driver = None

    @staticmethod
    def getDriver():
        if not Selenium._driver:
            chrome_options = Options()
            chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

            Selenium._driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        return Selenium._driver

    @property
    def driver(self):
        return Selenium.getDriver()

    def get(self):
        url = str(request.args['url'])

        self.driver.get(url)

        return make_response(self.driver.page_source)

api.add_resource(Selenium, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my scrapy spider which takes the benefit of that response to parse the title from a webpage.

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import quote
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class StackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&pageSize=50'
    base = 'https://stackoverflow.com'

    def start_requests(self):
        link = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?url={}'.format(quote(self.url))
        yield scrapy.Request(link,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css(".summary .question-hyperlink::attr(href)").getall():
            nlink = self.base + item
            link = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?url={}'.format(quote(nlink))
            yield scrapy.Request(link,callback=self.parse_info,dont_filter=True)

    def parse_info(self, response):
        item = response.css('h1[itemprop="name"] > a::text').get()
        yield {"title":item}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = CrawlerProcess()
    c.crawl(StackSpider)
    c.start()
```

> The problem is the above script gives me the same title multiple times and then another title and so on.

***What possible chage should I bring about to make my script work in the right way?***

Comment: Did you check the server log to find out why the connection was refused? The error message points towards problems on the server side, not the processing withing the script.

Answer (score 4):

I ran both the scripts, and they run as intended. So my findings :

1. `downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError` there is no means to get through this error without permission of the server, here i.e ebay.
2. Logs from scrapy:

   2019-05-25 07:28:41 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
   {'downloader/exception_count': 72,
   'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError': 64,
   'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 8,
   'downloader/request_bytes': 55523,
   'downloader/request_count': 81,
   'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 81,
   'downloader/response_bytes': 2448476,
   'downloader/response_count': 9,
   'downloader/response_status_count/200': 9,
   'finish_reason': 'shutdown',
   'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 25, 1, 58, 41, 234183),
   'item_scraped_count': 8,
   'log_count/DEBUG': 90,
   'log_count/INFO': 9,
   'request_depth_max': 1,
   'response_received_count': 9,
   'retry/count': 72,
   'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError': 64,
   'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 8,
   'scheduler/dequeued': 81,
   'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 81,
   'scheduler/enqueued': 131,
   'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 131,
   'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 25, 1, 56, 57, 751009)}
   2019-05-25 07:28:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (shutdown)

you can see only `8` items scraped. These are just the logos and other unrestricted things.

3. `Server Log` :

   s://*.ebaystatic.com http://*.ebay.com https://*.ebay.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-40GZDfucnPVwbvI/Q1ivGUuJtX8krq8jy3tWNrA/n58='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
   ", source: https://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=323815597324&t=0&tid=10&category=169291&seller=wardrobe-ltd&excSoj=1&excTrk=1&lsite=0&ittenable=false&domain=ebay.com&descgauge=1&cspheader=1&oneClk=1&secureDesc=1 (1)

Ebay does not allow you to **scrape** itself.

So how to complete your task >>

1. Everytime before scraping check `/robots.txt` for the same site.
   For ebay its : http://www.ebay.com/robots.txt
   And you can see almost everything is disallowed.

   User-agent: *
   Disallow: /*rt=nc
   Disallow: /b/*LH_
   Disallow: /brw/
   Disallow: /clp/
   Disallow: /clt/store/
   Disallow: /csc/
   Disallow: /ctg/
   Disallow: /ctm/
   Disallow: /dsc/
   Disallow: /edc/
   Disallow: /feed/
   Disallow: /gsr/
   Disallow: /gwc/
   Disallow: /hcp/
   Disallow: /itc/
   Disallow: /lit/
   Disallow: /lst/ng/
   Disallow: /lvx/
   Disallow: /mbf/
   Disallow: /mla/
   Disallow: /mlt/
   Disallow: /myb/
   Disallow: /mys/
   Disallow: /prp/
   Disallow: /rcm/
   Disallow: /sch/*%7C
   Disallow: /sch/*LH_
   Disallow: /sch/aop/
   Disallow: /sch/ctg/
   Disallow: /sl/node
   Disallow: /sme/
   Disallow: /soc/
   Disallow: /talk/
   Disallow: /tickets/
   Disallow: /today/
   Disallow: /trylater/
   Disallow: /urw/write-review/
   Disallow: /vsp/
   Disallow: /ws/
   Disallow: /sch/*modules=SEARCH_REFINEMENTS_MODEL_V2
   Disallow: /b/*modules=SEARCH_REFINEMENTS_MODEL_V2
   Disallow: /itm/*_nkw
   Disallow: /itm/*?fits
   Disallow: /itm/*&fits
   Disallow: /cta/
2. Therefore go to https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/developer/static/developer-landing.html and check their docs, there are easier example code in their site to get the items needs without scraping.